# How create React Typescript component with required and optional values but required value without default value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a lazy load component where I have 3 parameters:

1. children: is a component to pass to the `Suspense` component.
2. height: is the `height` for the `LazyLoad` component load icon.
3. width: is the `width` for the `LazyLoad` component load icon.

The `LazyLoad` component is the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Loading from "../Loading/Loading";

interface LazyLoadCompProps {
  children  :    React.ReactNode;
  height   ?:    string;
  width    ?:    string;
}

const defaultProps: LazyLoadCompProps = {
  children,
  height: "300px",
  width:  "300px"
}

const LazyLoad = (props: LazyLoadCompProps) => {
  const {children, height, width} = props;

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading height={height} width={width} />}>
      {children}
    </Suspense>
  );
};

LazyLoad.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default LazyLoad;
```

But when I start the app with `npm start` throw the following error:

```
TypeScript error in [project]/src/features/GenericComponents/LazyLoad/LazyLoad.tsx(5,21):
Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7031

    3 | import Loading from "../Loading/Loading";
    4 |
  > 5 | const LazyLoad = ({ children, height = "300px", width = "300px" }) => {
      |                     ^
    6 |   return (
    7 |     <Suspense fallback={<Loading height={height} width={width} />}>
    8 |       {children}
```

But I want the parameter `children` to be required but without optional value, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way would be to use the `React.FC` type. This will inject the `children` variable. You can also set the default variables inside the function parameters.

```
import React from "react";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Loading from "../Loading/Loading";

interface LazyLoadCompProps {
  height?: string;
  width?: string;
}

const LazyLoad: React.FC<LazyLoadCompProps> = ({children, height = "300px", width = "300px"}) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading height={height} width={width} />}>
      {children}
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default LazyLoad;
```

Comment: Thank you, is working and I like this one, looks compact and readable.

Comment: i always use it that way as i also like the readability :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I add the required and optional parameters in 2 different interfaces and then extends to another interface the optional and required like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Loading from "../Loading/Loading";

interface LazyLoadRequiredProps {
  children  :    React.ReactNode;
}

interface LazyLoadOptionalProps {
  height   ?:    string;
  width    ?:    string;
}

interface LazyLoadProps extends LazyLoadRequiredProps, LazyLoadOptionalProps {}

const defaultProps: LazyLoadOptionalProps = {
  height: "300px",
  width:  "300px",
}

const LazyLoad = (props: LazyLoadProps) => {
  const {children, height, width} = props;

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading height={height} width={width} />}>
      {children}
    </Suspense>
  );
};

LazyLoad.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default LazyLoad;
```

I see this example from the following source: https://dev.to/fullstackchris/react-with-typescript-optional-props-with-default-values-33nc